# Matching braces in php can be confusing

Tags: php

Can someone tell me the best way to learn how to tell which are matching braces below, like for example the 3 braces after the first else statement. Being a beginner this is very confusing. I currently use TextWrangler and see that it doesn't have that highlighting matching braces option.  The code is taken from Head First PHP & MySQL. I also have seen on so that the Gedit text editor has the option to highlight matching braces but can someone tell me some others. Thanks.

```
<?php
  require_once('appvars.php');
  require_once('connectvars.php');

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Grab the score data from the POST
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $score = $_POST['score'];
    $screenshot = $_FILES['screenshot']['name'];
    $screenshot_type = $_FILES['screenshot']['type'];
    $screenshot_size = $_FILES['screenshot']['size']; 

    if (!empty($name) && !empty($score) && !empty($screenshot)) {
      if ((($screenshot_type == 'image/gif') || ($screenshot_type == 'image/jpeg') || 
      ($screenshot_type == 'image/pjpeg') || ($screenshot_type == 'image/png'))
        && ($screenshot_size > 0) && ($screenshot_size <= GW_MAXFILESIZE)) {
        if ($_FILES['screenshot']['error'] == 0) {
          // Move the file to the target upload folder
          $target = GW_UPLOADPATH . $screenshot;
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
            // Connect to the database
            $dbc = mysqli_connect(localhost, root , root , guitarwars);

            // Write the data to the database
            $query = "INSERT INTO guitarwars VALUES (0, NOW(), '$name', '$score', 
            '$screenshot')";
            mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

            // Confirm success with the user
            echo '<p>Thanks for adding your new high score! It will be reviewed and 
            added to the high score list as soon as possible.</p>';
            echo '<p><strong>Name:</strong> ' . $name . '<br />';
            echo '<strong>Score:</strong> ' . $score . '<br />';
            echo '<img src="' . GW_UPLOADPATH . $screenshot . '" alt="Score image" 
            /></p>';
            echo '<p><a href="index.php">&lt;&lt; Back to high scores</a></p>';

            // Clear the score data to clear the form
            $name = "";
            $score = "";
            $screenshot = "";

            mysqli_close($dbc);
          }
          else {
            echo '<p class="error">Sorry, there was a problem uploading your screen shot 
            image.</p>';
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        echo '<p class="error">The screen shot must be a GIF, JPEG, or PNG image file no 
        greater than ' . (GW_MAXFILESIZE / 1024) . ' KB in size.</p>';
      }

      // Try to delete the temporary screen shot image file
      @unlink($_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name']);
    }
    else {
      echo '<p class="error">Please enter all of the information to add your 
      high score.</p>';
    }

  }
?>
```

Comment: Use an IDE or at the minimum, a popular text editor such as notepad++. These programs enable you to collapse code and jump directly to the matching brackets. The advantage of an IDE (such as netbeans) is that it shows potential parse errors. So you won't even have to run the file to find the error.

Comment: The best way is to use a decent IDE or editor that shows matching braces, or at least to indent your code cleanly

Comment: In addition to @ProfileTwist suggestion of an IDE, reducing the size of functions by pulling code out that can be externalized nicely into separate functions also helps with readability.

Comment: In regards to indents, you should either use a tab or 4 spaces for each new nested level of code. 2 spaces is no where enough - and is not traditionally accepted in the industry.

Comment: experience helps, the more you code the more you naturally see how it works.

Comment: I use enters before each {  so i have the } on matching indent. But after some time you learn to work with almost any code.

Comment: Thanks @ProfileTwist for the IDE suggestion.  I have been meaning to look into netbeans but I have found that while learning to is both fun, challenging and then more fun information overload kicks in and I found myself having to localize my thinking to one thing at a time just to keep from wasting time looking at all the cool stuff I would eventually be able to do.  Lastly, as far as the indents goes, the code above was copied verbatim from the HF book, while my personal code is so indented that I have to wonder am I overdoing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned a good IDE will go a long way in solving this for you however there's nothing saying you can't refactor the code to make it more readable as well.

e.g. if you were to pull out the various conditions into individual clear if statements you (and any co-workers) might find it easier to comprehend.

For example:

```
$screenshot = $_FILES['screenshot']['name'];
$screenshot_type = $_FILES['screenshot']['type'];
$screenshot_size = $_FILES['screenshot']['size'];

$parameters_set = false;
$acceptable_type = false;
$acceptable_size = false;

if(!empty($name) && !empty($score) && !empty($screenshot)){
    $parameters_set = true;
}

if($screenshot_type == 'image/gif' ||
   $screenshot_type == 'image/jpeg' ||
   $screenshot_type == 'image/pjpeg' ||
   $screenshot_type == 'image/png'){
       $acceptable_type = true;
}

if($screenshot_size > 0 && $screenshot_size <= GW_MAXFILESIZE){
    $acceptable_size = true;    
}


if($parameters_set && $acceptable_type && $acceptable_size){
    //do stuff!
}
```

There's a potential future benefit too in that if one of the "sub conditions" changes, adding the logic to say... require a minimum screenshot file size) you can modify the individual if statement that checks for the size conditions without having to find your way through a single, very complex if statement

Comment: Thanks scunliffe for the code above.  As a beginner, I can read your code much better than the code that I copied out of the book.  I have to wonder why the book wouldn't simplify their coding as yours above.